# Pandas: Accounting for Entry Discrepancies and Specific Column Values in Tabular Summaries

Tags: python, pandas

I've just started learning how to use Pandas and I'm trying to work with a fairly large dataset (5000 rows and 15 columns). The data has a format like this (to give an example of the issues I am facing and because I want to understand how to do this - the actual data has nothing to do with termination).

```
ID#    Firing Date     Age     State     Position       Cause
1      2011-07-03      29      NY        Salesman       Layoff
2      2014-03-20      25      AK        salesman       layoff
3      2004-08-11      42      CA        Receptionist   Tardiness
4      07/18/12        41      CA        Mechanic       Unknown
5      06/30/12        24      NY        Salesman       Harassment
6      05/20/12        31      NY        Mechanic       Harassment
```

I need to use data like this to create tabular summaries, but after poring through the pandas documentation and somewhat similar questions for hours I am still lost.

I believe I have figured out how to parse the dates by simply using that feature of read_csv(),

```
my_df = pd.read_csv('my_dataset.csv',
                    parse_dates = ['Hiring Date'])
```

However I can't figure out how to go about creating a summary that accounts for every row's value in a specific column. If that value is 'Salesman' or 'salesman' in that column, then I need to compare it to the hiring date (by year), with a third column for all 'Mechanic' values, and then a fourth column that totals all the remaining position types for each year.

So in the example data above, I would want to have an output that looks something like this:

```
Year      Salesman      Mechanic      Other      Total
2004      0             0             1          1
2011      1             0             0          1
2012      1             2             0          3
2014      1             0             0          1
```

I've been trying for hours, but the most I've been able to do is make a table that shows all the different possible position types (which in the actual data is close to 30), and I can't figure out a way to feed my needed slice of date so it only reads the year rather than the full date (and then groups by it).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Setup***

This is just data normalization

```
dct = {
  'Firing': pd.to_datetime(df.Firing).dt.year,
  'State': df.State.str.title()
}
```

---

Now using `pivot_table`, and finishing up by summing across the first axis:

```
out = (df.assign(**dct).pivot_table(
          index='Firing', columns='State', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0))

out.assign(total=out.sum(1))
```

```
State  Mechanic  Receptionist  Salesman  total
year
2004          0             1         0      1
2011          0             0         1      1
2012          2             0         1      3
2014          0             0         1      1
```

---

You could also replace the `pivot_table` with `crosstab` (using the same summation code after):

```
out = pd.crosstab(df.Firing.dt.year, df.State.str.title())
```